# Port fowarding: Emulate public IP on Ubuntu under Virtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I need to install a Demo application made in Ubuntu on a virtual machine running from within Windows 10 on a Laptop, to be presented to potential customers in different locations in the same country, but this application in the virtual environment should be viewed externally as having an exact IP. The reason for this is that we have a public IP (lets say, 11.22.33.44, hypothetical) provided by an ISP, and the access must be public; actually, one of the ways to validate the remote access is by the IP of that application. In fact, in this virtual device It will be running a *Client* service (via browser) through the customer's local network (eg 192.168.a.b), as the case below (fictitious values),

```
> ------------------ +
>                    [---------------]                   [------------]
> Guest (Ubuntu)     [ Host (W10)    ]                   [ Web Server ]
> Static IP          [ Static IP     ]--- Internet --- >>[ Static IP  ]
> 11.22.33.44        [ 192.168.0.100 ]                   [ 11.22.33.x ]
>                    [---------------]                   [------------]
> ------------------ +
```

But everything I've tried has not worked; I can not even perform a PING for any public IP successfully. In VirtualBox, I tried several combinations, like the following:

```
Settings >> Network >> NAT >> (virtuo-net) >> Port Fowarding
--TCP: HostIP = blank || HostPort = 6789 || GuestIP = blank || GuestPort = 80
--UDP: HostIP = blank || HostPort = 4567 || GuestIP = blank || GuestPort = 53
```

In the Guest (Ubuntu), I set the following configuration for the Network, via GUI interface as well as via **/etc/network/interfaces** (although it has already been mentioned here that GUI configuration takes precedence over manual configuration)

```
auto 
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface inet enp0s3 static
address 11.22.33.44
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 11.22.33.0
broadcast 11.22.33.254
gateway 11.22.33.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Could someone give an insight if I'm missing something?

Comment: NOTE: This question was originally asked at the "askubuntu" forum, but there it was stated that "superuser" forum is the suited place to pose a subject like this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are trying to use port forwarding – it isn't *even close* to what you're trying to do.

Instead, your client VM needs a VPN connection to the network where 11.22.33.44 would have been physically located.

#### Why won't "port forwarding" work

1. You're trying to add "port forwarding" rules to translate TCP and UDP. Ping is neither; it's ICMP.
2. You're trying to do outgoing connections from the VM, but the purpose of "port forwarding" is to translate incoming connections (i.e. DNAT from the host IP address to guest). SNAT would be more appropriate (if at all). If you choose the "NAT" network in VirtualBox, it automatically performs SNAT, but...
3. The ultimate purpose of both DNAT ("port forwarding") and SNAT is to translate the address. As you've configured 11.22.33.44 on the VM's network interface *and* want 11.22.33.44 to be visible by the outer Internet, it would seem that translation is exactly what you *don't* want.

#### Why won't *any of this* work

Let's say you have just the basic IP configuration: your guest OS is configured with 11.22.33.44/24 as its IP address, and with 11.22.33.1 as gateway.

Problem #2: Your example has the server's IP address on the *same* 11.22.33.0/24 subnet as the client VM has. If that's really the case, then your VM will assume the server is on the same "virtual LAN" as the VM itself – it will never *try* to reach it through the Internet gateway at all.

*(By the way, the broadcast address for 11.22.33.0/24 is 11.22.33.**255**, not 254. You could have avoided this error by not trying to manually specify the broadcast address at all: the OS can perfectly well calculate it on its own.)*

But let's say the server's IP address is actually on a different subnet (or maybe you're trying to ping Google). Then, yes, the client VM will try to send packets through its gateway towards the Internet. But here's what will happen:

- If the VM is configured for "NAT" networking, then VirtualBox will SNAT all outgoing packets so that they look as if sent from the host's own IP address (192.168.0.100 in this case). That's not what you want.

  After those translated packets leave the host PC and reach the customer's local router, it will again SNAT those packets so that they look as if sent from the customer's public IP address. And that's not what you want, either.
- If the VM is configured for "Bridged" networking, the guest OS will try to find its gateway on the customer's LAN – which of course doesn't have 11.22.33.1 in it.

If the VM is configured for "Host-only" networking and if the corresponding virtual LAN interface on the host OS is configured as 11.22.33.1/24 *and* if the host OS has IP routing/forwarding enabled (a bit troublesome on Windows), then the packet actually has a chance of leaving the host PC unmodified. But it won't go much further:

- It is very likely that the customer's LAN router will SNAT the packet anyway, putting the customer's public IP address as source instead of yours.
- If the router *didn't* perform SNAT and sent the packet unmodified, it'll probably be rejected by the ISP. (Many ISPs block packets with 'spoofed' IP source addresses, for hopefully obvious security reasons.)
- If the packet escaped both the router's SNAT *and* the ISP's anti-spoofing filters and successfully reached the target server... the replies would go to your company's network instead, as that's where the IP address is *really* located. In other words, random servers on the Internet really don't know that your laptop is "borrowing" that IP address.

#### How to make this work

In summary, even if you can reach the server, the server cannot reach you – either its replies stay in the same subnet, or they travel across the Internet, but in any case all packets meant for 11.22.33.44 will arrive at your 'home' ISP and then at your company's network.

So you need some way to *tell your company's network* how to reach the VM inside your laptop, so that the VM could receive packets meant for 11.22.33.44. That's generally done by setting up a *tunnel*, or a VPN. (Same thing really.)

You'll have to:

1. set up a VPN server at your company's network (if there isn't one already);
2. make the client VM connect to the VPN;
3. configure the VPN *server* to own the IP address 11.22.33.44 (one of several possible approaches, but possibly the simplest one).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, in fact VPN sounds like the suited approach, anyway I would like to keep the application running virtualized under Ubuntu as a Guest, not at the Host machine. I presume your (nice) answer take into account this scenario, right ?

Comment: If the app is in the VM, run the VPN client also in the VM... Most VPN protocols look like ordinary UDP streams, so it doesn't matter whether the client OS is virtualized or not.